# How to create string "Version 1.0" in C#

Tags: c#

I have to store versionName of a template. VersionName is autoincremented.If last versionName is "Version 1.0", next should be "version 2.0". First time when a template is created, I have to store "Version 1.0".

I am using

```
VersionName = "Version "+((LatestVersion+1).ToString())
```

LatestVersion holds the last version which is 0 in case added for first time.

This seems to be a ugly workaround and doesnot even yield Version 1.0. it yields Version 1. I Tried with Version class as well,it does not work. How to accomplish this.Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string.Format("Version {0}.0", LatestVersion + 1);
```

Assuming you never want anything other than `.0`.

The `Version` property under the `Assembly` has an overloaded `ToString()` method that will return various formattings.

Answer (score 1):

```
VersionName = string.Format("Version {0:d1}", LatestVersion+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is soo simple (no minor versions) then

```
string.Format("Version {0}.0", LatestVersion+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use minor version (1.X)
you could do this:

```
VersionName = "Version " + (LatestVersion + 1).toString() + ".0";
```

if you want to be able to use both Major (X.1) numbers and minors you could make a simple function like this for it:

```
SetVersionName(int Latest,int Minor = 0)
{
  VersionName = "Version " + (LatestVersion + 1).toString() + "." + Minor.toString;
}
```

then you could call SetVersionName(LatestVersion); to get "Version 1.0"
or:
int MinorVersion = 2;
SetVersionName(LatestVersion,MinorVersion); to get "Version 1.2"

you can also use AssemblyInfo to get the app version set in the application file and add .toString() on that.